# How to find if sheet is empty?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting the data range of a sheet and using `Range.getNumRows()` to get the number of rows in a Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

But when the sheet happens to be completely empty, `Range.getNumRows()` still returns 1 instead of 0. I am guessing this is because a range has to have at least 1 cell.

Is there another (simple) way to get the number of rows in a sheet without having this Problem?

I know I could loop through all cells in the sheet to check it is completely empty, but this doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: I figured this _had_ to be a duplicate... surely somebody had asked it before! But, no... Good question!

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled across the answer on the app script documentation.

I am using [sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) now

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to get the sheet range and concatenate it to check if any data is found.

```
function isSheetEmpty(sheet) {
  return sheet.getDataRange().getValues().join("") === "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

range.isBlank() work's well too.

[Apps Script Range isBlank](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#isblank)